# How to use CSV with Qt MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, csv, qt4

How do I use CSV database with Qt+MySQL? I would like to do this with something like MS C#'s `Schema.ini` + Jet Provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can read/write csv database with ODBC drivers but I am afraid this is windows only.
Just setup your database like this:

```
db="DRIVER={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=E:\\;Extensions=csv,txt"
```